# Why Jer. 31 on Rosh Hashana?

Tags: rosh-hashanah-new-year, haftarah, yirmiyahu--book-of

On the second day of *Rosh Hashana*, after reading about the *akeda* (and some other stuff), we read [*Yirm'ya* 31](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/T1131):1–19 as the *haftara*: why this *haftara*?

Answer (score 6):

The *Haftorah* is very moving and probably hold the record for the most Jewish songs from one *Haftorah*! It especially relates to the Rosh Hashanah theme of ***Zichronos*** ("Memories").

First, ([verses 1-13](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1131.htm#1)), the *Haftorah* discusses God bringing the redemption, which may connect to the theme of *Zichronos*, as it involves God "remembering" the Jews. Next ([verses 14-16](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1131.htm#14))  is the scene of Rachel weeping and God promising redemption, which is part of the theme of *Zichronos* - recalling the patriarchs or matriarchs as a merit to end the exile.

Then ([verses 17-18](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1131.htm#17)) describe Ephraim's *teshuvah* (repentance), including the different parts of *teshuvah*, an important thing to mention during the *Aseres Yemei Teshuvah* (Ten Days of Repentance):

> כִּי אַחֲרֵי שׁוּבִי נִחַמְתִּי וְאַחֲרֵי הִוָּדְעִי סָפַקְתִּי עַל יָרֵךְ, בֹּשְׁתִּי וְגַם נִכְלַמְתִּי כִּי נָשָׂאתִי חֶרְפַּת נְעוּרָי
>
> Surely after that I was turned, I repented, and after that I was instructed, I smote upon my thigh; I was ashamed, yea, even confounded, because I did bear the reproach of my youth.

Finally, as Rashi on Megilla 31a ([s.v. "הבן יקיר לי אפרים"](http://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Megillah.31a.19.1?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all)) points out, [verse 19](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1131.htm#19) cites God remembering Ephraim and having mercy on him, which, appropriately enough, is one of the verses of *Zichronos* included in the Rosh Hashanah *mussaf*.

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer. It is going to go very well in [*Days of Awe - Mi Yodeya?*](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/and-revision-and-houses-of-prayer-and-tzedaka-distribute-the-goodness-of-mi-y).